# Xcode issue on file name

Tags: xcode, swift

Here are 2 issues in my project (Swift) at the moment:

No 1:   
- If I named a file as *name1.swift* or *name2.swift* than Xcode recognized the ViewController inside and shows it in Custom Class field.  
- When I named that file as *name3.swift* or *name4.swift* Xcode does not show the controller in Custom Class.

No 2:   
*File1.swift*:   
    `class A: UIViewController {}`

*File2.swift*:

`Extension A: protocol_X {
}
class B {}`

When I use this code Xcode does not show controller A in Custom Class field. But if I move the code   
    `Extension A: protocol_X {
    }`
   
to *File1.swift* then Xcode shows it there.

I want to use *name3.swift*. I want to keep Extension part in *File2.swift* follow my app architecture.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, is that you renamed the file in Finder, not in Xcode.

Xcode has a very peculiar way of handling files and folders. For instance when you make a group in Xcode it shows up as a folder, but doesn't actually create a folder on your hard drive.

I would ask this as a comment but unfortunately i'm 42 rep short: have you tried deleting and re-adding the file to your project again?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to delete and re-add the file but no result. I add the file in to project as reference so when I rename it in XCode, the file name in system file (Finder) is changed too.